# How can i remove white space under footer?

Tags: html, css

I am using css

```
/* This css is for sticky footer*/
#ft {
    background-color: #445379;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    height: 42px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 42px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

I changed the position from `fixed` to `relative` then there is a white space showing up. How can i remove it. it is fine while the position is fixed.

Comment: if you want to use position:relative; try removing bottom: 0; if that doesn't help please give a link to your site

Comment: I don't get any white space... what browser are you using ? http://jsfiddle.net/xuz51wzu/ or edit fiddle to show your problem

Comment: change position fixed to absolute and check

Comment: @Miam84 he says he changed the position from fixed to relative to get the white space. With fixed position and bottom:0 you would'nt get a white space

Answer (score 2):

The white space may be from the body element. Most css resets/normalisers remove it. try:

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `position: relative;` you can move elements around the page but it will still keep its original form on its original position. like you would cut out a square from the middle of a piece of paper. You will still have the hole in the paper when moving the square.

Use `position: absolute;` if you want the white space gone.

Hope that makes sense.

Also, set the parent element to `position: relative;` if you do not want the absolute positioned element to jump over the page when positioning it.

Answer (score 0):

html code

```
<div id="all-site-wrap">
        <nav></nav>
        <content></content>
        <footer></footer>
 </div>
```

in the styles

```
 .all-site-wrap{
     display:flex;
     min-height:100%;
     flex-direction:coloumn;
     justify-content:center;
  }
```